# How to modify the attributes in a DynamoDB GSI?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB GSI with only certain fields in the projection(attributes). I would like to add a new field to this list of attributes. Is it possible to do this without deleting the GSI and recreating it? I did not find an option to do that in DynamoDB console or in [update_table cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/update-table.html).

Comment: having the same issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not possible. Need to recreate GSI again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [UpdateTable API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html) it is only possible to create and delete GSI. So to update the current GSI, the old GSI needs to be deleted and recreated again.